# solutions to flow free game

Tags: graph-theory

In flow free, the goal is to connect dots with the same color using pipes, and pipes may not cross. (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bigduckgames.flow)
Every square in the grid has to be filled with pipes.

While writing a solver for this game, I came up with an answer that was way to slow to be practical for large puzzles. Then I came across somebody who noticed that almost every puzzle has a solution for which there are no two consecutive corners in the same direction.

So there are is always always a solution without:

```
 -- --
|     |
```

//

```
|     |
 -- --
```

//

```
 --
|
|
 --
```

//

```
--
  |
  |
--
```

If you implement that rule, the solver gets a significant speedboost (stronger constraint propagation).
When is that rule valid? It is immediatly obvious that it is not always valid but is there a way to prove that there exists a solution without those corners in certain cases? It would be nice to garantuee I can find a solution that way, even in a subset of all possible cases

Comment: I don't understand this question at all.  I can easily do even the largest grids of Flow Free, but I don't know what you mean at all by "consecutive corners in the same direction."